# Scss variable path for importing other scss files

Tags: sass

With the latest version of SASS/SCSS, is it possible to setup variables for the @import action like so...

```
$mpath: "~/../../../node_modules/";
@import {$mpath}+"bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

The above is syntax is obviously wrong on @import, but hopefully you get the point ;)  Can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do interpolate a variable is like this:

```
$mpath: "~/../../../node_modules/";

@import "#{$mpath}bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This would insert the value of the variable in the path and import the Sass file.

Comment: I'm using "Live Sass Compiler" for Visual Studio Code, and with your suggestion, its telling me that this is a Compilation error, on the @import line.

Comment: @blackhawk: Is it a syntax error or an error in the file path? I tried running it on Sass Meister and it doesn't show any syntax error? Maybe you can test it with a relatively simpler path to ensure the code is correct